# Name of these lemmas in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, axioms, philosophy

> Lemma 1.2
> If $S$ is countable and $S'\subset S$, then $S'$ is also countable

> Lemma 1.3
> If $S'\subset S$ and $S'$ is uncountable, then so is $S$.

I was wondering if there was a name for the logic/proof that these two lemmas act upon. That if a component lacks a quality, it disqualifies the greater set containing that component from having that quality. And the other, that should a component have a quality (in this case, uncountability), then so does its greater set containing it.

Is there a name for this reasoning?

[image: cratylus]My question is derived from Plato's Cratylus, where Socrates essentially makes the argument that:

1. There are true and false propositions.
2. A proposition being true is contingent on the parts (by Socrates, called names, which loosely translates to words) of the proposition also being true
3. That the part of a true proposition must also be true, and of a false proposition false.

I thought his rational was similar to the lemmas used for sets, how for the set to be countable (true), the parts (elements) must also be true.

Comment: I've heard people say that a property of sets is "downwards closed" if every subset of a set satisfying the property also satisfies the property.  You might also say the property is "closed under taking subsets."  I've also heard "upwards closed," especially in the context of one of the axioms of filters.

Comment: Perhaps to Socrates could be give a counterexample where the implication $F \Rightarrow F$ is the truth. And as to your first question, may be, are useful words "reduction" and "expansion".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say 1.3 follows from 1.2 using uncountable = not countable and excluded middle:

- given $S' \subset S$, $S'$ uncountable.
- Suppose $S$ were countable.
- 1.2 says that $S'$ is countable.
- This contradicts $S'$ not countable from the given data.
- so the assumption $S$ is countable was wrong:
- ergo $S$ is uncountable.

1.2 is the basic fact: countable sets are "downwards closed", 1.3 is a derived fact and needs no new principle.